# if() is still executing even after condition fails in c program

Tags: c, if-statement

I wrote a program in C.  I was using `goto` statement then I thought it is fault of the `goto` statement but then I used simple `printf()` statement and found that it wasn't the fault of the `goto`, but the fault of the if-statement.  Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float power(float a, float b);

int main()
{
    char z;
    float x, y;

    printf("please,enter the number on which you want to raise \nand the 
    number by which you want to raise other number respectively:- ");
    scanf("%f %f",&x,&y);

    printf("%f \n",power(x,y));
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("do you want to enter the numbers again? y/n:- ");
    scanf(" %c",&z);

    if(z == 'y');
    {
        printf("y\n");
    }
}

float power(float a, float b)
{  
    float d = pow(a,b);
    return d;
}
```

and here is the output

```
 linuxman@Aspire:~/c programs/a raised to b$ ./a.out
 please,enter the number on which you want to raise 
 and the number by which you want to raise othe number resplectevly:- 4 2
 16.000000 
 do you want to enter the numbers again? y/n:- n
 y
 linuxman@Aspire:~/c programs/a raised to b$
```

I had entered `n` and even this prints `y`.  Why is this happening?

Comment: fflushing stdin is undefined behaviour - you wanted to fflush stdout probably...

Comment: What's the point in the pointless wrapper for `pow`?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined. On linux, it will AFAIK just do nothing.

Comment: Formatting/indentation;(

Comment: ... and wording/punctuation

Comment: 'if(z=='y');' that's the end of the statement.  next line follows.  If you had indented the code sanely, you would probably have caught the semicolon issue.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit or used [`-Wall -Wextra`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765105/918959)

Comment: Remove the semicolon after if

Comment: Rebuild it.  Make sure you're running what you build.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit sorry,it is ok now i was forgot to put :w in vim

Comment: Oh vim.... all is revealed :(

Comment: @ThingyWotsit how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon after the predicate of the if (i.e. (z == 'y')) should be removed because the statement that you placed after it was intended to be the consequent of the if statement.  So that part of your code should read instead:

```
if(z=='y')
{
   printf("y\n");
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I glossed over that the first time I read it.

Answer (score 4):

Compiled with GCC 6.3.0-12ubuntu2 and warnings **enabled**, one gets:

```
% gcc sfdafd.c -lm -Wall -Wextra
sfdafd.c: In function ‘main’:
sfdafd.c:16:11: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an ‘if’ statement 
                [-Wempty-body]
 if(z=='y');
           ^
sfdafd.c:16:1: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... 
               [-Wmisleading-indentation]
 if(z=='y');
 ^~
sfdafd.c:17:1: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly 
               indented as if it is guarded by the ‘if’
 {
 ^
```

I normally don't answer to typo questions, but perhaps you should consider turning on some switches / upgrading your compiler linuxman.

Comment: but when try to upgrade it,it say  sudo apt upgrade gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:5.3.1-1ubuntu1).
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: it already latest in my Ubuntu 16.04 mate

Comment: @linuxman that wasn't the point. Compile with *at least* `-Wall -Wextra`, then you will get these warnings. In case you really didn't understand: remove the `;` after the condition. It's an *empty statement*, so with it, `if` will become meaningless.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I am not sure if 5.3.1 gives the same warnings :D -- edit nvm, even GCC 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 gives them.

Comment: @linuxman I have 3 suggestions to you: 1. Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. 2. Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. 3. Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra`. P.s. try adding `-Werror` too...